# C++ OpenCV : Masking the frequency domain image

Tags: c++, opencv

I have obtained the *dft output of an image* and then tried to save the real part of the image I get a completely black one. When I display the real part of it I get a good spectral image. I want to know, can I use different processing techniques like *line Finders*, *circle Finders*, *count non zero functions on a frequency domain image*?

Comment: Check type, normalize to uint8 if necessary.